# Imgur can't upload "message": "Failed stripping metadata"

Tags: api, express, upload, metadata, imgur

I'm making an api getting a gif that uploads it to imgur,
but when requesting the api (express or postman),
i receive an error (everything works fine with other pictures):

```
 {
  data: {
    error: {
      code: 1001,
      message: "Failed stripping metadata",
      type: "Exception_Logged",
      exception: {}
    },
    request: "/3/upload",
    method: "POST"
  },
  success: false,
  status: 500
}
```

How to avoid this error ? How to correct this picture ? "Adding metadata ?"
Is it due to the fact the picture was saved with ffmpeg ?

**When i upload with the imgur pannel, everyting is fine,but not with the api**

Thanks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeikb.jpg

Note: i suppose the medata were removed by imgur, but I only can give that, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. In my case the cause was the wrong encoding of the data in `image` parameter, it needs to be URL encoded (i.e. by using `encodeURIComponent()`).

My code uploads the contents of a Canvas object in PNG format and looks like this:

```
function encode(x)
{
    return encodeURIComponent(x.substring(x.indexOf(",") + 1));
}

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(e) { console.log(e); };
xhr.onerror = function(e) { console.log(e); };
xhr.open("POST", "https://api.imgur.com/3/image");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID <your client id here>");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("image=" + encode(canvas.toDataURL()));
```